# Auth0 Angular parseHash returns undefined

Tags: angular, jwt, auth0, angular2-jwt

I am using auth0-jwt to handle authentication:

```
this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
  if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
    window.location.hash = '';
    this.setSession(authResult);
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  } else if (err) {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
});
```

However, while `window.location.hash` contains authResult: 
    `#access_token=qwe&expires_in=7200&token_type=Bearer&state=zbc&id_token=xyz`, `auth0.parseHash` returns invalid token and `authResult` is undefined
I am using :
`"@auth0/angular-jwt": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
 "auth0-js": "^9.2.2"`

Comment: Hi Yuvals - did you solve this? I keep getting an invalid_token error:

```{error: "invalid_token", errorDescription: "Issuer DOMAIN is not valid."}```

Comment: @JackVaughan if you are using social login such as Facebook, make sure you use your own app credential, and not what is in the example of Auth0. I believe that was my issue.

Comment: if not, make sure you define the correct domain on both auth0 and your app

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Yuvals - turns out my domain was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using wrong Domain for both application and what is defined on Auth0